# Lightswitch HTML Client Progress Bar using SignalR

Tags: html, signalr, visual-studio-lightswitch

my original post/question can be found here..

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7e818ea5-3b95-4028-a2bf-7ff7f329ee7d/html-client-progress-bar?forum=lightswitch

I am building a Lightswitch HTML LOB desktop application in VS2013 that does a lot of server side processing against a large number of records per transaction (50,100,1000 records).  When a user triggers a server side transaction, I'd like to show a "real time" progress bar...

I've tried this...

https://westcountrydeveloper.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/client-server-progress-bar-using-signalr/

...but I just can't quite seem to get the wiring correct...any nudges or examples would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: What code have you got so far?